# Which COCO data set was used for training ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz model from Tensorflow repo?

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for `COCO` dataset which was used for training of `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz` model available on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md webpage.

Coco download webpage http://cocodataset.org/#download contains various versions like `2014`,`2015`,`2017`. Which of them was use to train this model?

Comment: Eager to know this as well. Any luck?

Comment: Bump - would also like to know.